# Как передать в вызываемую функцию значение вложенной таблицы?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Есть таблица:

```
ADDRESS (
  id     number,
  city   varchar2(100),
  street varchar2(500)
)
```

Есть тип:

```
create type address_type is table of address;
```

Есть функция, которая принимает параметр типа `address_type`.

Как с помощью JDBC его передать?

Пыталась создать объект, аналогичный таблицe и сделать `setObject()` - не работает.

Comment: Вы хотите в таблицу занести java объект?

Answer (score 3):

> Есть тип create type address_type is table of address;

Нельзя объявить тип со структурой таблицы:

```
create table address (
    id number generated always as identity, city varchar2 (100), street varchar2 (500)
);
create or replace type addressRows is table of address;
/
```

> PLS-00329: schema-level type has illegal reference to DB.ADDRESS

Стоит в "листе желаний для следующего релиза", но пока ещё не реализовано. Задайте поля явно и должно получится:

```
create or replace type addressRow force as object (city varchar2(100), street varchar2(500));
/
create or replace type addressRows is table of addressRow;
/
create or replace package addressPkg as
    function saveAddresses (addresses addressRows) return number;
    procedure execute (memo in  varchar2) as
    language java name 'Address.main (java.lang.String[])';
end;
/
create or replace package body addressPkg as
    function saveAddresses (addresses addressRows) return number is
    begin 
        insert into address (city, street) select * from table (addresses)
        ;
        return sql%rowcount;
    end;
end;
/
```

Java код:

```
create or replace and compile java source named "Address" as
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;

public class Address {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver ().defaultConnection ();
        CallableStatement cstmt = null;
        System.out.println(">>> begin " + args[0] + " ...");
        try {
            cstmt = conn.prepareCall ("{ call ? := addressPkg.saveAddresses (?) }");
            Struct[] objs = new Struct[3];
            objs[0] = conn.createStruct ("ADDRESSROW", new Object[] {"City 1", "Street 1"});
            objs[1] = conn.createStruct ("ADDRESSROW", new Object[] {"City 2", "Street 2"});
            objs[2] = conn.createStruct ("ADDRESSROW", new Object[] {"City 3", "Street 3"});
            Array arr = ((OracleConnection) conn).createARRAY ("ADDRESSROWS",  objs);

            cstmt.setObject (2, arr);
            cstmt.registerOutParameter (1, Types.INTEGER);
            cstmt.execute ();
            int rows = cstmt.getInt (1);
            System.out.println("<<< end " + rows + " rows saved.");
        }
        catch( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally { if (cstmt != null) cstmt.close(); }
    }
}
/
```

Запуск:

```
exec addressPkg.execute ('save addresses')
select * from address;
```

выведет:

```
>>> begin save addresses ...
<<< end 3 rows saved.

        ID CITY       STREET   
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 City 1     Street 1  
         2 City 2     Street 2  
         3 City 3     Street 3
```